# Limit of cosines product

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $\displaystyle P_n:=\prod_{k=1}^n \cos\frac{\pi}{k+2}$. Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} P_n$.

I've only shown that the limit is positive.

Let $\vartheta_k:=\pi/(k+2)$. We have $\log P_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \log\cos\vartheta_k$. Now, 
$$\log\cos\vartheta_k=-\frac{1}{2}\log(1+\tan^2\vartheta_k)>-\frac{1}{2}\tan^2\vartheta_k=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin^2\vartheta_k}{\cos^2\vartheta_k}>-2\vartheta_k^2.$$
Therefore we can write that
$$\log P_n>-2\pi^2\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(k+2)^2}>-2\pi^2\int_2^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}=-\pi^2$$
i.e. $P_n>e^{-\pi^2}$.

Comment: Your second inequality is not right.  I think you need to sum  $1/(k+2)^2$.

Comment: Typo, you're right.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Do you know if a "closed form" exists?

Comment: A friend of mine gave me the problem...

Comment: possibly useful fact: $\int \tan(x) dx = -\log(\cos(x))+C$

Comment: wolframalpha : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+cos%28pi%2F%28k%2B2%29%29%2C+k%3D2+to+infinity

Comment: I don't think this has any closed form solution. Are you qute sure you have the problem statement right? If the denominator was something like $2^{k+2}$ you'd get a very nice solution.

Comment: @Alex: I know, that's the famous Viete's infinite product :)

Answer (score -1):

We may use the product for $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ to conclude that
\begin{align}
\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \cos\frac{x}{n} &= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \prod_{k = 0}^\infty \left( 1 - \frac{4x^2}{(2k + 1)^2 n^2 \pi^2} \right)\\
&= \prod_{k = 0}^\infty \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \left( 1-\frac{4x^2}{(2k + 1)^2 n^2 \pi^2} \right)\\
&= \prod_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{\sin\frac{2x}{2k + 1}}{\frac{2x}{2k + 1}}
\end{align}
which could be used to approximate your product.